# Is HTTP2 + SSL faster than HTTP without SSL?

Tags: http, http2

As the title says,

I currently have a website with https on sensitive pages and cached http on the rest for speed.

I know HTTP2 is faster than HTTPS. What I don't know is whether HTTP2 is faster than regular un-encrypted HTTP?

Would I see performance improvements if I encrypted everything with SSL and enabled HTTP2, compared to using HTTP without encryption but with caching?

Comment: It depends a lot on the site. If you are serving a static HTML page with no external css, javascript or fonts, just using HTTP will be faster. From my experience though stepping out of these tight constraints is all too easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends on your site.

However, saying that, [there is practically zero noticeable speed penalty for using HTTPS nowadays](https://istlsfastyet.com) - unless you are on 20 year old hardware or serving huge content (e.g. you are a streaming site like Netflixs or YouTube). In fact even YouTube switched to HTTPS for practically all their users: https://youtube-eng.blogspot.ie/2016/08/youtubes-road-to-https.html?m=1

There is a small initial connection delay (typically 0.1 of a second) but after that there is practically no delay, and if on HTTP/2 then the gains that m will give to most sites will more than make up for tiny, unnoticeable, delay that HTTPS might add.

In fact, if you have some of your site on HTTPS already, then either you are using HTTPS resources on some of your site (e.g. common CSS that both HTTP and HTTPS pages use) and already experiencing this delay, as you need to connect over HTTPS to get those even when on HTTP, or you are making them available over both and making your HTTPS users download them again when they switch.

You can test the differences with a couple of sample sites on my blog here to give you some indication of differences: https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/http-versus-https-versus-http2/ - which is a response to the https://www.httpvshttps.com website that I feel doesn't explain this as well as it should.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you. My hosting provider does offer caching over HTTPS, so I ended up cloning my server and running some tests. One on http with caching and CDN, one on http2 with HTTPS caching and HTTPS CDN. The noticeable difference is the initial response time. Fastest load went from 1.7 seconds to 2.8 seconds. However, I could probably shave this off with some tweaking, but it looks like on my hardware (Digital Ocean) the site loads marginally faster with http compared to https. With that said the difference is negligible given the benefits of https.

Comment: 1 second initial load delay sounds like a lot. Check your HTTPS setup at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest and in particular what ciphers you are using. Not sure how much control over this you have though if Digital Ocean handle HTTPS setup.

Comment: I ran the test, what am I looking for? I got an overall rating of A with cipher caching at 85 / 100. 

This is what's on top in order of server preference:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS

Comment: That's a modern, fast cipher. Also means you're using a modern version of SSL/TLS library (e.g. openssl). Is the cert key size (1st section) 2048 bits? Is session resumption (bottom section) yes for either caching or tickets. Any warnings at all on the report?